# Jquery - Add entry to the rightclick contextmenu

Tags: jquery

you can disable the menu

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

you can show a div

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {

    $('#menu').css({
        top: e.pageY+'px',
        left: e.pageX+'px'
    }).show();

    return false;

});
```

but is it possible only to add an entry to the  rightclick contextmenu?

Thanks in advance! 
Peter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in JavaScript no...this could have some pretty malicious uses.

You can create your own menu (like your `<div>` example), but not add items to the native browser context menu.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Have a nice weekend :)

Comment: Hi @Nick, can you give some example of malicious use. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to HTML5 this is possible now: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/html5-context-menu.php

Comment: This is quite neat, although it only works on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice jquery plugin, called "contextMenu" :)

http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

I use it and its very easy to customize.