# Adding Entries to Context Menu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, right-click

I've seen this question before on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793703/jquery-add-entry-to-the-rightclick-contextmenu)) but I've seen it happen, right-clicking on JWPlayer displays options like "About JWPlayer", etc.

Anyone know how JWPlayer did it, even if it isn't JS?

Comment: Done - thanks, never really remember to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins like Flash can create context menu items, but only when the user right-clicks within the plugin's container (so a single Flash video can't alter the menu for right-clicks that happen elsewhere on the page).

[JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players) is essetially a Flash-based player with an HTML5 fallback.  If you disable Flash in your browser and force HTML5/JavaScript, you'll see that the context menu is the default menu. JavaScript can't alter the context menu; Flash can.

Comment: I thought JWPlayer was JS-based? HTML5 or something... Thanks for the info!

Comment: It *can* use HTML5 video, but only when Flash isn't available.

Comment: Ah. Thanks again! Although I feel like HTML5 video is preferable due to mobile support.